# Exclude unit tests from Code Clones analysis

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, refactoring, automated-tests, static-analysis

How do I exclude my unit test project from Visual Studio's Code Clones analyzer.

Hence, I am more interested in my automated test scripts serving as living documentation than I am as SOLID. As a result, I am okay with some duplication across my suite of tests.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `.codeclonesettings` file to the project to specify exclusions.  See the **To exclude specific files or methods from the analysis** section at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh205279.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 for details.